# Как получить данные из select angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular2

У меня таким образом получилось взять данные из инпута, 
а вот с селектом так не работает, кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста?

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Education level</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="education" name="education" class="form-control">
      <option></option>
      <option [ngValue]="Junior">Junior</option>
      <option [ngValue]="Middle">Middle</option>
      <option [ngValue]="Senior">Senior</option>
      <option [ngValue]="other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    education: String;
}
onRegisterSubmit(){
  const user = {
  education: this.education
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в `ngValue` поставить кавычки, т.е. `[ngValue]="'Junior'"`

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало, только еще без ng, просто [value]="'Junior'"